# Second Blueprint registered in Flask Restplus does not show up in swagger

Tags: flask, flask-restplus

Given this Flask Restplus app:

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

base_api_blueprint = Blueprint('base_api', __name__)
base_api = Api(base_api_blueprint)

bff_api_blueprint = Blueprint('bff_api', __name__)
bff_api = Api(bff_api_blueprint)

@base_api.route('/base', endpoint='base-endpoint')
class BaseResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"from":"base"}


@bff_api.route('/bff', endpoint='bff-endpoint')
class BffResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"from":"bff"}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(base_api_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(bff_api_blueprint)
api = Api(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

When I navigate to the swagger doc at `http://localhost:8080/` I see the swagger for `base_api_blueprint` but nothing for `bff_api_blueprint`.  If I reverse the order of the `register_blueprint` calls (so `bff_api_blueprint` is registered first), the opposite happens -> the swagger for `bff_api_blueprint` shows, with nothing for `base_api_blueprint`.

Regardless of what the swagger says, both blueprints are operational i.e. they return HTTP responses.

How can I "merge" the swagger of both blueprints into one?

Comment: I reworked this successfully using Flask Restplus Namespaces, but leaving this question here in the hope that I can be taught something :)

Comment: Ever get a solution ? I am having the same issue and wondering if stick with blueprints or switch to namespaces .

Comment: never found a solution mate, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, if you want to combine documentation then you will be using one Api instance like so:

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

base_api_blueprint = Blueprint('base_api', __name__)
# base_api = Api(base_api_blueprint)
api = Api(base_api_blueprint, doc="/combined/") #the end point to your combined documentation api

base_ns = api.namespace('base_api', description='Base API')
bff_ns = api.namespace('bff_api', description='Bff API')

# bff_api_blueprint = Blueprint('bff_api', __name__)
# bff_api = Api(bff_api_blueprint)

@base_ns.route('/base', endpoint='base-endpoint')
class BaseResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"from":"base"}


@bff_ns.route('/bff', endpoint='bff-endpoint')
class BffResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {"from":"bff"}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(base_api_blueprint)
# app.register_blueprint(bff_api_blueprint)
api = Api(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

This approach also uses namespaces and now your end points will end up like this:

```
/combined/
/base_api/base
/bff_api/bff
```

If you have organised your project using blueprints, you can import the same api instance into other sections of the project. From [Flask-RESTplus documentation](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html), namespace is the same pattern as Flask’s blueprint.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have both blueprints show up on their own swagger pages, you need to use the "url_prefix" argument in the blueprint definition, as such:

```
from flask import Blueprint, Flask
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource

base_api_blueprint = Blueprint('base_api', __name__, url_prefix="base_api")
base_api = Api(base_api_blueprint)

bff_api_blueprint = Blueprint('bff_api', __name__, url_prefix="bff_api")
bff_api = Api(bff_api_blueprint)
```

Each blueprint will have a swagger page that can be found on http://localhost:8080/base_api and http://localhost:8080/bff_api.

If on the other hand, you want both endpoints showing up in the same swagger, the way to go is using a single Blueprint and multiple Namespaces.